# Missing the "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server X.X" folder

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I have been using mysql for quite a while now. But earlier this week when I was trying to install Ruby on Rails, I noticed that the "`MySQL Server 5.5`" (or anything like SERVER folder) was missing. So I upgraded to `mysql-installer-community-5.6.11.0.msi` and now I have all these folders under MySql....

```
 - MySQL Connector J 
 - MySQL Connector Net 6.6.5 
 - MySQL Documentation 5.5.31 
 - MySQL For Excel 1.1.1 
 - MySQL Installer 
 - MySQL Notifier 1.0.3 
 - MySQL Workbench 5.2 CE 
 - MySQL Workbench CE 5.2.41 folders
```

BUT STILL NO "MySQL Server"!! what am I missing? I need that folder in order to install gem in Ruby (`http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-umoWOjJ3gc @ 14:50 mark`) Can anyone here PLZ help me? How/where can I find that folder and add it to my MySql folder? I asked the same question in MySQL Forums 2 days ago...still no response.

I really need help :/ 
Thank you!

**UPDATE**

Daniel Renshaw was right. even though i went with the default setting while installing mysql 5.6, the server box was unchecked. after re-installing it, everything were where they are suppose to be. Thank you :)

Comment: I don't see any reference to SQL Server around the 14:50 mark, but I do at the 07:35 mark. There they use the path `C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5`. (I haven't watched the whole video)

Comment: okay....you can also try this link http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MX6wYbsUO-Y at the 0:20 mark. I have to insert this line: `Subst X: "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you installed the 32 bit or 64 bit version?

The 64 bit version is found in `C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6` by default.

The 32 bit version is found in `C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6` by default.

However either default can be overridden.

To find out where it is actually installed, go into the `Services` administration tool in Windows (e.g. via control panel, or by opening services.msc), scroll down to `MySQL56` (or other version if other installed), right click and select `Properties`. The server installation location can be seen in the `Path to executable` text. This text should include the `<PATH>\bin\mysqld...`. You need to use the `<PATH>` part instead of the default location.

Comment: thank you for your response. i know where i have installed it. it is in "C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL" and in that folder there is only those 8 folders...no Server folder

Comment: The "MySQL Server 5.6" folder *is* the "server" folder.

Comment: he he he....i know that! and that's what i'm trying to say that under my C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL there is no such folder as either "MySQL Server 5.6" or "MySQL Server 5.5"

Comment: Look in the services list as I originally suggested and you'll find out where it is actually installed since it's clearly not in its default location. If it's not in the services list then the server is not actually installed.

Comment: Answer updated. Get the path to use from the services tool as suggested.

Comment: i know it's going to sound stupid...but there is no MySQL56 (or MySQL55 or any name starting w/ MySQL) under Start>Administrative Tools>Services (!?!) really confuse now :S

Comment: Then the server is not actually installed. You need to go through the installer again and pay attention to all the options.

Comment: iirkh! okay...i'll do that now. Thank you